# DART : Why dart apps are so big in size? (console app)

Tags: windows, dart, native, dart2native

i made a console app  with dart that calculates 2 numbers and prints them 
the size came about 5 MB !!

Download link (Windows only) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sxlvlSZUdxewzFNiAv_bXwaUui2gs2yA

Here is the code

```dart
import 'dart:io';

int inputf1;
int inputf2;
int inputf3;

void main() {
  stdout.writeln('Type The First Number');
  var input1 = stdin.readLineSync();
  stdout.writeln('You typed: $input1 as the first number');
  sleep( Duration(seconds: 1));
  stdout.writeln('\nType The Second Number');
  var input2 = stdin.readLineSync();
  stdout.writeln('You typed: $input2 as the second number');
  sleep( Duration(seconds: 1));
  inputf1 = int.parse(input1);
  inputf2 = int.parse(input2);

  inputf3 = inputf1 + inputf2;
  print('\nfinal answer is : $inputf3');
  sleep( Duration(seconds: 10));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason for the big executable is because the `dart2native` compiler is not really made to make a executable you can directly run on your machine from scratch. Instead, it package the `dartaotruntime` executable together with your AOT compiled Dart program.

The `dartaotruntime` contains all the Dart runtime libraries and dart2native does not remove anything from the `dartaotruntime` (also difficult since it is a binary) so you will get the whole runtime even if you only adds two numbers.

But it is not that bad since it is an one-cost penalty for every program. So if you make a very big program, the `dartaotruntime` are still only include once.

However, if you are deploying many small programs in a single package I will recommend you add the `-k aot` parameter to `dart2native` so it instead of an executable will generate an `.aot` file which you then can run with `dartaotruntime <program.aot>`.

This will make your deployment a bit more complicated but you will just need to provide the `dartaotruntime` binary together with you multiple `.aot` files.

I have compiled your program to both `.exe` and `.aot` on Dart for Windows 64 bit. version 2.8.2 so you can see the size difference:

[image]

Again, `-k aot` will not save you any disk space if you are only going to deploy a single executable. But it can save a lot if your project contains many programs.

It should also be noted that the `.aot` file is platform dependent like the `.exe` file would be. And you should use the same version of `dartaotruntime` which has been used to compile the file.

Answer (score -2):

It is because natively dart app are made by incorporate the render engine...  I know that is right for all the flutter app which are based on dart.
Look at this too https://medium.com/@rajesh.muthyala/app-size-in-flutter-5e56c464dea1

Comment: but i am making console app not a flutter app